# Uploading files using jquery in asp.net asynchronously

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I was working on a project and it required me to upload image files (preferably all kinds of files). The requirement is that it should upload asynchronously but it seems to me that as I am not using HTML5 and my project is in ASP.NET 2 (or can be upgraded to 3.5) & C# (Web Forms), I think there are possible limitations in doing that.

I saw a plugin http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ and tested it in my browser, and Firebug shows that it posts the image files on the server using XHR, and the `Post` had something like:

```
-----------------------------25131776232422 Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name="files[]"; filename="myfile.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg
ÿØÿà�JFIF��`�`��ÿî�Adobe�d����ÿá]Exif��MM�*����2�������b;�������vGF�������GI����..............
```

That I assume to be the bits for my uploaded file, so how do I post it on server using XHR or any jQuery api(), and how do I read it and save it using an asp web-form. It should be great if you could help me solve server side issue i.e. read the bytes and save it as image.

Please do not suggest a plugin that works this, as I need to start it from scratch.

Comment: Well you have your answer in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if ( files != null )
        {
            // do something fancy with the files
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
```

Given something like the method above exists in an controller, make sure your plugin makes a post on /{my_fancy_route}/save. You should be able to access the file-contents and for example, save it.

Comment: I can't say if it works or not, but there is no way mentioned to process on client side. I mean any jQuery `api` haven't been used here.

Comment: Well, it solves "It should be great if you could help me solve server side issue i.e. read the bytes and save it as image". As for the other part, i recommend to get familiar with the html5 file api if you target html5 compliant browsers.